# Upload the images out of server context and load it as image in jsp

Tags: jsp, applicationcontext

I need to upload an image to a folder, the folder name can be configured in a configuration.properties file. The file path can be outside the application context. After uploading the image, i need to show it in as image in JSP via img tag
How could i do it?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it looks like you are able to save file to desired location, but are not able to show images from that location.

Well, you cannot refer to files that are outside of web container. Source of img tag in html can be URL i.e file in web container or file that is hosted on web.

As a work around, you can create a servlet that can load file from outside of your web container and then write/stream file to your response. You will provide path of file to the servlet and that servlet will serve the file to you.

Suppose if you create a servlet for serving file with name 'FileServlet', and this FileServlet takes 'imageName' as parameter to fetch file. Your FileServlet is coded to take file from path say 'C:\image\'. img tag like:

```
<img scr="FileServet?imageName=image1.jpg">
```

could be used to serve file 'C:\image\image1.jpg.

refer [FileServlet by BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/07/fileservlet.html) for detailed working.